# ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Controller' not found - Kohana 3.0.3 Error

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana

I am (newbie) using Kohana V 3.0.3 and my directory structure is:
pojectsys (kohana's system directory) parallel to htdocs directory

C:\xampp\pojectsys

and my application directory is in htdocs

C:\xampp\htdocs\examples

Inside C:\xampp\htdocs\examples\index.php, following variables have been set:

$application = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\examples\application';
$system = 'C:\xampp\pojectsys';

Now when I am trying to execute http://lc.examples.com/ then Kohana returns error:

ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Controller' not found for line 3

class Controller_Welcome extends Controller {

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the default index.php that should solve your problem because the system folder is not in 'C:\xampp\pojectsys'; but in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\examples\system';

if you hardcode this stuff the hole thing will only work on your machine. so again use the default index.php

Comment: Thanks antpaw,

Problem has been rectified.